# How do I disable 'Activities' hot corner in GNOME shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, activities-overview

GNOME shell has the so-called feature "hot corner", that opens the dashboard  if the mouse touches the top-left corner of a monitor screen.

I want this disabled I used to have a GNOME shell extension, yet the repository is not found anymore:

```
git clone git@github.com/Ahrak/gnome-shell-extension-disable-hot-corners.git
fatal: repository 'git@github.com/Ahrak/gnome-shell-extension-disable-hot-corners.git' does not exist
```

Comment: A reminder for users of ubuntu 22.04 and who installed "Hide Top Bar" extension: Try toggle off its "show panel when mouse approach edge of screen" option.

Answer (score 130):

## Recent GNOME Versions

Recent GNOME versions don't require `gnome-tweak-tool` to change this.

You can find a switch for *Activities Hot Corner* in GNOME Settings application under *Multitasking* category.

[image: Multitasking Category in Gnome Settings application]

#### A screencast (with `gnome-tweak-tool`):

Instructions for legacy GNOME releases (GNOME Tweaks required).

[image: Hot corner configuration in gnome tweak tools screencast]

Comment: If you are writing in English, show your screen shots in English to. I do not see any of this as the third option down, mine looks very different.

Comment: I've added a link to a screencast with an english interface.

Comment: Which version of Tweaks is that? I don't have this option in 3.28.1.

Comment: I currently have gnome-tweak-tools 3.28.1-1 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @mmai this [patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/merge_requests/45) is giving you the option on Ubuntu. :-)

Comment: this works until i lock the screen and unlock it again to resume my session. any thoughts on how to make this setting "stick"?

Comment: OMG thanks - this was bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work when I suspend/resume.  See @user230910's answer.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you

Comment: I have newest (GNOME Tweaks 3.34.0) Tweaks, and there is NO option for HOT CORNER

Comment: proper answer is:

***gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners false***

Comment: @razor I get `No such key “enable-hot-corners”`. I have gnome-tweaks 3.30.2-1 and gnome 3.30+1 on Debian 10

Comment: If you failed to find the setting, it usually means that your gnome-shell is too old. You should either upgrade your gnome to 3.36+ (if your distribution allows), or use a gnome extension (refer to my answer).

Comment: Never ran GNOME until now, but this was driving me crazy!  Used `gnome-tweak` and it was the very first setting under Top Bar.  Disabled and works great!  Thanks!  +1

Comment: This option does not exist in 22.04 or later.

Answer (score 46):

#### Command-line way

If you are looking for the `gsettings` command for this "*Activities Overview Hot Corner*" option in *GNOME Tweaks*:

[image]

then, the key is `gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners` `true`|`false`

example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners false
```

[image]

---

***EDIT***

Recent version of GNOME seems to be

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners false
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks!
One more question: How did you "merge" the bash and the top-bar into one, single bar at the bottom?

Comment: The setting was move to `org.gnome.desktop.interface`

Comment: @aross you are rite.. I have updated/Edited the answer.. Thanks!!!

Comment: yw, and thx for a great answer.

Comment: i'm using Debian 10, and the settings is in neither `desktop.interface` nor `shell`. Where can I find it?

Comment: Simplest of all the fixes.

Comment: @xdavidliu If you failed to find the setting, it usually means that your gnome-shell is too old. You should either upgrade your gnome to 3.36+ (if your distribution allows), or use a gnome extension (refer to my answer).

Answer (score 17):

Tried frans' solution:

```
git clone github.com:HROMANO/nohotcorner.git nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr:
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why not install the gnome-shell-extension directly? It's much easier, and works for gnome in every linux distribution.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/

---

**Update for gnome>3.36:**

This extension is not needed anymore as it is now supported by the shell itself. You can switch off the hotcorner with a gsettings or using gnome-tweak tool.

Answer (score 12):

If you have already enabled the infrastructure to use Gnome-Extensions, you can simply go to the extensions webpage, search for "hot corners" and click the switch to turn it on.

Here is an example of the url:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/

Here is a screenshot of the button to switch on:

[image: Screenshot of extendsions.gnome.org link]

Obviously this assumes that you have already installed all the bits to make extensions work from the website - see the section on installing shell extensions from a browser here:

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-gnome-shell-extensions-gui-cli/

Answer (score 8):

Take [k0pernikus](https://askubuntu.com/users/32792/k0pernikus)' answer but name the directory correctly:

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
git clone github.com:HROMANO/nohotcorner.git nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr
```

works for me

Answer (score 7):

Funny how an ancient post pops up and does not have a recent answer, non of the solutions work for recent versions of Gnome Shell.

For Fedora Worstation 36 with Gnome Shell 42.4, this can be found in settings under multitasking, see screenshot (Active Screen Edges can be switched there too):

[image]

I assume Gnome 43 will have this too.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22, this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The option to disable the "hot corner" wasn't available on the latest version of **gnome-tweak-tools** up to this answer date, so I manage to add the option with an extension: [disable hot corner extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/)

[image: Extension options]

Just download the compressed file and add it the "Extensions" option, after that enable or disable the "hot corner" as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to [No Topletft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) by [HROMANO](https://github.com/HROMANO/nohotcorner/)

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
git clone github.com:HROMANO/nohotcorner.git
```

Comment: You need to call this extension `nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr` - at least in the current version. The extension won't start otherwise and you get an error message `Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: Could not load extension nohotcorner: Error: uuid "nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr" from metadata.json does not match directory name "nohotcorner"`

Comment: yes, those who read this: use @frans answer above

Comment: I get permission denied trying to clone.

Answer (score 1):

Install Gnome Tweak Tools with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool.
```

Once installed open the tweak tool app and go to the option marked extensions on the left:

Next go to the following location [HERE](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) and download the "No Top Left Corner" extension by Azuri. This is an extension to work with Gnome-Tweak Tool. When you download, you will be asked for the gnome shell version you are using. You can check it with the following command:

```
gnome-shell --version.
```

Once downloaded, go back to the Tweak Tool and  at the end of the extensions list is a File button to add more extensions. Click it, and then select the zip file containing the shell extension downloaded.

That's it. It may require a restart. For me it asked for a restart, but even before that the hot corner was off.

Comment: The No Top Left Corner is  not required. The GNOME Tweaks has a `Activities Overview Hot Corner` toggle in `Top Bar` option in the sidebar.