# How can I disable the hot corner /Activities corner using the Terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 18.10, gnome-shell-extension

How can I disable the hot corner /Activities corner using the Terminal?

I know I can use the Tweak Tool, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701592/how-to-disable-hot-corner-in-gnome-shell/1097386#1097386), but I am writing a little bash script to reconfigure my Ubuntu Gnome quickly to my needs so I would like to use e.g. `gsettings` for that.