# How to enable dash to only be displayed when I press Super key?

Tags: dock

On Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop I would like to:

1. Hide the Dash.
2. Only to be displayed when I press Super key.

In Settings | Appearance | Dock - I have enabled the "Auto-hide the Dock", this solved No. 1 requirement.

For No. 2, when I move mouse to the edge (when Dock should be) I don't want Dock to be automatically displayed. I only want Dock to be displayed when I press Super key. How to do this?

P.S. I know this should be working, because I have set somehow on another computer, but now I can't figure it out how to do it on another PC.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/701592/739431 may this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing bellow two commands from terminal and my problem is solved.

Set Dock to auto hide:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false
```

How fast mouse movement towards Dash direction is needed for Dock display to be be triggered. Default is 100. Set arbitrary high value like 1000 and human can't move mouse so fast to ever get displayed.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock pressure-threshold 1000
```